# Can't append Data to current User in Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have following code:

```
  let selectedYearPicker = data[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    print(selectedYearPicker)


let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid ?? "x"
              Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID)
    
    db.collection("users").document(userID).setData([
        "gender": selectedYearPicker
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
```

It prints successfull, but it is writing in a new document in the database...

Screenshots:

[image1 of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFJyA.png)

[image2 of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU6Ru.png)

Comment: Which is the correct user ID? The one starting with `v` or `x`?

Comment: with the x, with the v it is the empty one with only the gender data

Comment: You've been through so many iterations of this on the other question, I'd start to wonder where the info has been written from. For instance, somehow you wrote data with a `uid` key that isn't actually your UID? I'd delete your documents (since it looks like you're just starting) and try running the app again and see what actually gets added.

Comment: I changed a little bit of code and now it is overwriting it :D

Comment: Good. You can remove questions that are resolved or add your own answers to show what you had to change.

Comment: I now have it. "merge: true" as second parameter solved my question. It is now not overwriting. If it gets in a new document, the UID is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection("users").document(userID).setData([
    "gender": selectedYearPicker
], merge: true)
```

Comment: yes merge: true was the thing I forgot. Thx